# Planting potatoes between tomatoes, bad or good idea?

Tags: vegetables, tomatoes, potatoes

I spaced my potatoes about 3 feet and between each I would like to put about 3 tomatoes to save space. Will this create problems in the near future?

Comment: The second "potatoes" should be "tomatoes", right? Please [edit], if necessary.

Answer (score 7):

It's harder to control blight when the two are planted in close proximity.  Late blight caused a devastating epidemic in the 1840s in the North Eastern USA. http://vegetablemdonline.ppath.cornell.edu/factsheets/Potato_LateBlt.htm

But there are plants that have cherry tomatoes grafted onto potato stock eg. http://www.edible.co.nz/fruits.php?fruitid=77 which I guess is a case of putting all your eggs into one basket.

Anyway, generally, don't intercrop potatoes with tomatoes.  It's harder to control diseases if you do.

Comment: Blight would be a huge concern

Comment: Has this garden of yours been used previously for tomatoes, potatos, peppers?  If not then knock yourself out.  Potatos mature very quickly and the tops will die out way before your tomatoes mature.  Do not use uncertified seed potatoes (ie, from friends, the back of your pantry).  Never buy seeds for anything unless CERTIFIED non GMO.  Next year do not plant potatos, tomatoes or peppers in that area or even near that area.  Gotta think ahead to the next season and rotation is a critical element for the success of a vegey garden!! Planting likes with likes is a good thing most instances!!

Answer (score 5):

When it gets hot and humid tomatoes grow fast, and they can block the light to the potatoes which don't grow so big.

Answer (score 5):

In general, try not to mix plants of the same family (and in this case both share *Solanum* as genus), both for competition on same nutrients (they share similar metabolism), and their can share diseases.

Tomato plants don't have deep roots, so I think you can have problem harvesting potatoes without damaging the tomatoes.

EDIT:

I never had problem with shadow: I don't think tomatoes does so much shadows, and potatoes (and tomatoes) growth well in the shadow of trees.